# C# Web scraping Knowledge Panel/Google Page using AngleSharp with CSS Selector

Tags: c#, web-scraping

**Context:** I am trying to web scrape a part of the google page, the knowledge panel specifically for restaurants. To retrieve the searched venue's name, address, hours, website link, phone number, etc and other such information that comes up within its business page. (Right-hand side of the google page)

The NuGet Package installed & used is AngleSharp.

**Problem:** After attempting to latch on the CSS Selector, within debug mode, it says "Enumeration yielded no results" and consequently I receive no output.

I believe the program is unable to properly latch onto the correct CSS selector.

What may be the solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance :)

```
namespace WebScrapingTutorial
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        internal async void ScrapeWebsite()
        {
            var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
            
            //Example restaurant
            var address= "https://www.google.com/search?q=the+ledbury+restaurant+london&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB914GB914&oq=the+ledbury+restaurant+london&aqs=chrome..69i57j46j0l4.147j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8";

            //cellSelector contains CSS Selector of the restaurant's address
            var cellSelector = "#rhs > div > div.kp-blk.knowledge-panel.Wnoohf.OJXvsb > div > div.ifM9O > div > div.SALvLe.farUxc.mJ2Mod > div > div.EfDVh.mod > div > div > span.LrzXr";

            var cells = document.QuerySelectorAll(cellSelector);
            var titles = cells.Select(m => m.TextContent);

            //Output
            foreach (var title in titles ) { rtbData.Text = title;  }
        }

        private void btnScrape_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScrapeWebsite();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [website accessed via a browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nm5Lx.png) you want to scrape.  The [same website received by the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSt5H.png) is sometimes slightly different, varies from website to website.  Therefore the CSS Selector should be obtained from the website that is received into the program (the latter) to solve the following issue.